# How to make a trapezoid with nested for loop?

Tags: python-3.x

Can someone help find a way to make a trapezoid with nested for loop?
I made this but it keeps making more stars there needs to be. Could someone please give me suggestions.

```
import time
row1 = int(input("What is the length of the top side: "))
star = ("*"*row1)
height = int(input("Enter the height of this trapezoid:"))

for row in range(1, height + 1):`
    # print out the right number of spaces
    for spaces in range(1, height - row + 1):
        print(" ", end = "")
        time.sleep(0.5)

    for asterisks in range(row):
        print(star, end = "" )
    print()
```

Comment: it'd be good to show the output of your code as well as the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is flawed, you are printing star variable multiple times, so there are too many starts, you need to increase the number of stars by 2, not multiply the number of stars.

```py
for row in range(height):
    # print out the right number of spaces
    for spaces in range(height - row-1):
        print(" ", end = "")
        time.sleep(0.5)

    for asterisks in range(row1+row*2):
        print('*',end = "" )
    print()
```

if you don't need the time.sleep(), you can do it in a single loop.

```py
for row in range(height):
    print(" "*(height-row-1),"*"*(row1+row*2))
```

Comment: Thank you. But I think it should be row1-2+row*2 to show the trapezoid with the top length being what the user wants it to be. But this was very helpful.THX.

Comment: ohh, I didn't count the stars when I tested it, just the linear increment. And now I look at it, the problem isn't that I have to do -2, it is that you have done `1,sth+1` in all your ranges that's why the variable `row` is one extra and `*2` makes excess 2 stars. don't be afraid to start from zero.